# Swagger for a chat server over a websocket?

Tags: chat, swagger

I want to write a webapp that has a chat server component. I'll use swagger for my main REST API, but I also want to use something similar for a chat server over a websocket. I'm really looking for serialisation/deserialisation of messages, message validation, transport, etc. I.e. all the boring stuff.

Is it possible to use swagger for this, or can people suggest something else that might help me? At the moment the chat server is home made based on redis, but I *might* switch to ejabberd or something else if I can find something that does what I need.

Comment: This just got an upvote. For anyone still looking, checkout http://www.grpc.io/ which solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Swagger provides you with a convention for documenting your API not implementing it.

As per the oficial documentation:

> The goal of Swagger™ is to define a standard, language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which allows both humans and computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service without access to source code, documentation, or through network traffic inspection.

This means that swagger in itself is used to build and visualize API documentation.

What your looking for however is not an API documenting tool. You can achieve your goal with an XMPP protocol library such as Smack. See here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

Comment: I know what swagger is but I want something similar for running over websockets for a chat server. I.e. Something that will give me objects that can be populated for the messages sent in each direction, and that will handle the serialisation/deserialisation of messages, validation, etc.

Comment: The answer is then no. Swagger can only allow you to create and visualize documentation.

Comment: Well it doesn't because there are code generators which are obviously what I'm referring to.

Comment: I think XMPP protocol is what you need in that case. Most of the semantic for chat is already defined and you can even extend it to cover your own custom needs.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond true, you can do it using XMPP (while you can't with swagger). There are various librabries which can help, for example Smack http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/.

Comment: @Mark Smack for XMPP looks like what I'm after. If you update your answer for that I'll accept it. Thanks.